# Store \today value with \DTMsavedate

Tags: expansion, date, datetime2

#### Goal

With `datetime2` package I try to save the “`\today`” date with `\DTMdatesave` command, but it successively fail.

#### My tries

##### 1. The dumb method

I began with the most evident way. Putting directly `\today` as a second argument of `\DTMdatesave`.

```
\DTMdatesave{today}{\today}
```

But, as expected it failed with the following error message:

```
\ifcsdef {@dtm@datestyle@iso}{\csuse {@dtm@datestyle@iso}}{\PackageError \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsedate was complete.
<to be read again>                
                   \par
```

I think it failed probably because the `\today{}` command didn’t print the ISO format date (YYYY-MM-DD).

##### 2. Giving ISO formatted date

Then, I use `\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}` command from `datetime2` to convert `\today` output into an ISO format:

```
\DTMsavedate{today}{\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}\today}
```

But it also give me the following error :

```
\ifcsdef {@dtm@datestyle@iso}{\csuse {@dtm@datestyle@iso}}{\PackageError \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsedate was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.10
```

##### 3. Saving the command expansion

So, then, I thank I should give a saved output with `\let` command.

Then, I did:

```
\newcommand\preparetoday{\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}\today{}}
\let\temptoday\preparetoday
\DTMsavedate{ShootDate}{\temptoday}
```

And it failed with same error message than the 1st method.

#### Question

How to store the “`\today`” date in a `datetime2` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the provided `\DTMsavenow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMsavenow{today}

Today: \DTMusedate{today}

\end{document}
```