# How can I save \today using \DTMsavedate?

Tags: beamer, datetime2

This question is almost identical to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611241/69445), but unfortunately the proposed solution there does not work in my scenario.

I'm trying to write a package for a certain beamer style and additional commands. To this end, I save the date provided with the `\date` command and use it with a certain format in several places (e.g., footer, title page). This works fine when I put a concrete date as the argument of `\date`, but when I use `\today` instead, I encounter an error. Here is my M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\DTMsavedate{mydate}{#1}\DTMmakeglobal{mydate}}

\date{2022-09-18}
% \date{\today} % ! Paragraph ended before \@dtm@parsedate was complete.

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\DTMusedate{mydate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Simply using `\DTMsavenow` as in [this answer to the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611245/69445) does not help since I do not know what users of the package will put in `\date`. I experimented with more or less the same things described in [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611241/69445) and had the same failing results. I also tried to use `\expandafter` in the new definition of `\date`, but did not manage to make that work. How can I make the `\date` command accept both concrete dates and the `\today` macro and be able to use the specified date anywhere by `\DTMusedate` (or any other means)?

Comment: I suggest to initialize your date with `\DTMsavenow` and then provide a custom macro with which your users can overwrite the date by asking them for 3 numerical arguments. You can use this to build a date which meets the requirements of datetime2. The problem with using `\date` is that this is a freeform field. If your users can use this, you won't know if the date is in the required format for `datetime2`, you don't even now if it is a date at all, it might just be some other text.

Comment: If you want your users to keep using `\date`, you could initialize it with `\date[\the\day\ \DTMenglishmonthname{\the\month} ]{\the\year}` in your package and then use `\insertdate` and `\insertshortdate` in your theme. Yous users could then manually change it with `\date[18 September]{2022}` or whatever they want.